# Spreadsheet().insertSheet(index, name) does not insert the sheet at index but as the last sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I execute this code I expect the Generated sheet to be inserted right after the active sheet. But that's not the case, it's always created as the last sheet.

Let's say I have 2 sheets : `activeSheet` and `notActiveSheet` and I run this code:

```
  var indexActiveSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getIndex()
  var nameActiveSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()
  Logger.log(indexActiveSheet,nameActiveSheet)
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(GENERATED);
  if  (sheet == null){
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(GENERATED, 1 + indexActiveSheet)    
  }
  Logger.log(sheet.getIndex(), sheet.getName())
```

But the logs and the spreadsheet shows that's not the case :

```
[20-10-18 14:42:17:468 CEST] 1.0 activeSheet
[20-10-18 14:42:17:811 CEST] 3.0 Generated
```

I was expecting

```
[20-10-18 14:42:17:468 CEST] 1.0 activeSheet
[20-10-18 14:42:17:811 CEST] 2.0 Generated
```

Answer (score 2):

### Issue / Explanation:

- [getIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getIndex()) **starts at 1** and this is why you get the index of
  the `activeSheet` to be 1.
- On the other hand, in [insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname,-sheetindex)
  `sheetIndex` **starts at 0**.

If you see the official documentation for `insertSheet`:

> The index of the newly created sheet. To insert a sheet as the **first
> one** in the spreadsheet, **set it to 0**.

- Namely, if you want to place the `Generated` sheet after the
  `activeSheet` you need to call:

  ```
  insertSheet(GENERATED, indexActiveSheet)
  ```
- For example, in your case, `indexActiveSheet` is **1**. To place the
  `Generated` sheet to the **second** position, you also need **1** because
  this is what `insertSheet` accepts if you want to place it at the
  second position. Remember, in `insertSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex)` `sheetIndex=0` is the **first** sheet, `sheetIndex=1` is the **second** sheet.

---

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var GENERATED = 'Generated';
  var indexActiveSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getIndex()
  var nameActiveSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()
  Logger.log(indexActiveSheet,nameActiveSheet)
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(GENERATED);
  if  (sheet == null){
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(GENERATED, indexActiveSheet)    
  }
  Logger.log(sheet.getIndex(), sheet.getName())
  
}
```

---

### Improvements (optional):

You don't need to call `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet` so many times when you can simply store into a variable and use that variable instead:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var GENERATED = 'Generated';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var act_sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var indexActiveSheet =  act_sh.getIndex()
  var nameActiveSheet =  act_sh.getName()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(GENERATED);
  if  (sheet == null){
    sheet = ss.insertSheet(GENERATED, indexActiveSheet)    
  }
}
```